# Make a window of size L on a graph

Tags: python, numpy, graph, networkx

I have a networkx lattice which looks like this-

```
m=100
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(m,m,periodic=True)
```

This is a lattice of dimension mxm.  Now I want to create a window of dimension l where l is from 0

At every window of size l I need to count the number of nodes in the lattice which are infected.
This information I already have created and can be called using a function to get the information about a particular code.
How do I code this? An idea would be sufficient I dont need any code.
The window starts from the centre of the lattice.

Comment: So you're trying to count the number of nodes of a given status that lie in the region `[0,L]x[0,L]`?

Comment: @Joel yes i am doing that